# php mysql DELETE does not work

Tags: php, mysql

In a my DB, I want to delete rows which date field is < current date using PHP script.

```
$date('Y-m-j');
$result = mysql_query("DELETE * FROM festival WHERE day = '$date'");
```

For same reason, DELETE does not work. The same query using SELECT do.
Perarps it is due to some permission about DELETE command?

Comment: You're deleting everything where your date _is_ (=) the date specified... not where it is less than (<).

Comment: don't need the * either just DELETE FROM will be fine + what Ben said above

Comment: mysql_query('DELETE FROM `festival` WHERE `day` <= CURDATE();');

Comment: Would actually be this assuming the field is one of the mysql date format fields and nost just a varchar field `mysql_query('DELETE FROM festival WHERE day <=NOW() ');`

Comment: the =  is an example, I try with <.   The same instruction with SELECT works but DELETE not.

Comment: May I recommend that in the future you copy and paste your query into a database explorer (such as MySQL Workbench or PHPMyAdmin). Either of these tools would have told you that you had a syntax error. You can also get the final query by saving it to a variable, logging it, and then pulling it out of your logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is incorrect. The DELETE query does not take a column list, but you're trying to pass it one (as `*`).

Your query should simply be:

```
DELETE FROM festival WHERE date = '$date'
```

Comment: +1 I would also suggest it may be easier to just use `WHERE date = CURDATE()`

Comment: See, he wants `date field is < current date`

Comment: Thanks. Mine was a very stupid error.